# Cannot use apt on WSL2 but ping works

Tags: networking, ping, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt, wsl2

I'm trying to use a WSL2 installation of Ubuntu.

`apt-get` does not work. For example if I want to install `net-tools` I obtain

```
daniele@IOS-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  net-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 196 kB of archives.
After this operation, 864 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 net-tools amd64 1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60+git20180626.aebd88e-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The strange thing is that I'm able to ping both the IP address and the name of the server:

```
daniele@IOS-PC:~$ ping 91.189.88.152
PING 91.189.88.152 (91.189.88.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=50.0 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=50.5 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=51.1 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.152: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=50.7 ms
^C
--- 91.189.88.152 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.006/50.578/51.086/0.386 ms
daniele@IOS-PC:~$ ping archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=53.4 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=51.0 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=50.8 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=51.4 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=50.0 ms
64 bytes from aerodent.canonical.com (91.189.88.142): icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=50.2 ms
^C
--- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.958/51.127/53.421/1.135 ms
```

How can I use the `apt-get` command correctly?

Comment: Can you access other locations using `wget` (or the like)? Can you access locations in your local network? There was/is [a bug in AVM FritzBox routers](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3493) that affected WSL 2 traffic.

Comment: Ok It was the FritxBox... Thanks.

Comment: @DanielB: You might wish to put up an answer, as this was verified by the poster.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent past, I was affected by a similar issue where I could not pull Docker images with the new Docker Desktop (based on WSL 2). Others had already experienced it, too, and found the issue: [There is a bug in the hardware-accelerated firewall in AVM FritzBox routers.](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3493)

The only “solution” (workaround, really) is to turn off the firewall accelerator. To do this, go to `http://fritz.box/support.lua` (or `http://192.168.178.1/support.lua` or whatever) and log in. Somewhere on this page you will find a checkbox to control the firewall hardware acceleration. In German, it looks like this:

[image: packet acceleration options]

Just disable it and give it another try.

**Be warned though**: This will severely limit routing performance of your FritzBox. If you have a fast internet subscription, you will feel it.